# How to pass Array from Parent component to Child component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in my project, the First component is App I got this App component when I created a project. And Second Component is ClassRoom. Now in `App.js`, I have an array, In that array, I have four different names. Now I have to pass those four names for my child component that is ClassRoom. I know how to loop an Array of objects to React. But I don't know how to loop Array and pass that array to child component so help me to achieve this task.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ClassRoom from './ClassRoom/ClassRoom';

function App() {
  const students = ['shiva', 'krishna', 'ram', 'madhav']
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <ClassRoom></ClassRoom>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #09d3ac;
}
```

This is ClassRoom.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './ClassRoom.css'

export default class ClassRoom extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is ClassRoom.css

```
There is no css in ClassRoom.css
```

My expected output is I need to pass students Array from Parent Component which is `App.js` to Child Component which is ClassRoom.js.
If not, clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `<ClassRoom students={students}/>`

And in ClassRoom componenets access it using `this.props.students`

Answer (score 1):

**In App.js**

```
function App() {
  const students = ['shiva', 'krishna', 'ram', 'madhav']
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <ClassRoom studentsArray = { students } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**In ClassRoom.js**

```
export default class ClassRoom extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <ul>
               {this.props.studentsArray.map( student => `<li> ${student} </li>` )}
             </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ClassRoom component is functional component, then use this.

```
<ClassRoom students={students}/>

 function ClassRoom(props) {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {props.students}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ClassRoom;
```

In functional component use props.students and in class component use this.props.students